# Scala classpath not finding default package class in local directory

Tags: scala, classpath

Consider a v simple scala object with the following first two lines (default/no package) and a main():

```
object CpuTest {
 def main(args: Array[String]) = {
      ..
```

Compiling works fine

```
stephen@i386:/shared/OpenChai/dstat$ scalac CpuTest.scala
```

Here are the classes:

```
stephen@i386:/shared/OpenChai/dstat$ ls -l *.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephen stephen 1150 Jun 10 20:06 CpuTest$$anonfun$1.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephen stephen  667 Jun 10 20:06 CpuTest.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephen stephen 1748 Jun 10 20:06 CpuTest$.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephen stephen 2175 Jun 10 20:06 CpuTest$MyThread$1$$anonfun$run$1.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephen stephen 1444 Jun 10 20:06 CpuTest$MyThread$1.class
```

And **javap** is happy with it:

```
stephen@i386:/shared/OpenChai/dstat$ javap CpuTest.class
Compiled from "CpuTest.scala"
public final class CpuTest {
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

But I can not get the classpath to work to run this class:

```
export CLASSPATH="$(pwd)/*"

echo "$CLASSPATH"
/shared/OpenChai/dstat/*

stephen@i386:/shared/OpenChai/dstat$ scala CpuTest
No such file or class on classpath: CpuTest
stephen@i386:/shared/OpenChai/dstat$ scala -classpath "$CLASSPATH" CpuTest
No such file or class on classpath: CpuTest
```

This should be dead simple. What am I missing?

**Update** I found a workaround:  need to add "." to the classpath:

```
scala -classpath "$CLASSPATH":. CpuTest
```

Now I do not understand why that should be:  the original CLASSPATH already includes the .class file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misusing the

```
<path>/*
```

in the classpath: the wildcard only supports jar files, not .class files.

Comment: It also includes pwd by default.